# Colspan=2 in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to have `colspan=2` in `gridview`? I want the `gridview` to have 2 columns under 1 header. How can I achieve this? I tried following code but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas??

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderStyle Width="40px" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#DDDDDD" BorderStyle="Solid" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="img_center" />
        <HeaderTemplate><b>Action</b></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" height="20" width="20" alt="Edit" title="Edit"></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <a href="#"><img src="images/view.png" height="20" width="20" alt="view" title="view">
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is how gridview should look:
[image]

The image shown is a table with 3 columns Sr., Action and Dept name. Action column has colspan=2, hence there are 2 columns under Action column.

Comment: I have used Gridview because I want to display a set of data in a table format. It cannot be done in Gridview?

Comment: **[Link 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249155/Rows-and-Columns-Merging-in-ASP-NET-GridView-Contr)**  and **[Link 2](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-Merging-GridView-Header-Columns-Cells-by-adding-Multiple-Headers-Header-Row-in-ASPNET.aspx)** and **[Link 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16049/Merge-Header-GridView-DataGrid)**

Comment: Thanks for the links. It helped alot but still I am unable to implement it my solve my problem.

Comment: I have updated my question to show how I want the final result.

Comment: Can you please explain it, in your image header has two columns right??

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian I have update my question please take a look.

Comment: yes the image what i see in your post is having a common header that is you have merged header column and not the value column..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I finally achieved it:

```
protected void gridList_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("colspan", "2");
        }
}
```

First I added 4 colums to the gridview (Sr., ActionEdit, ActionView, DepartmentName) and then merged cell 2 and 3 to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Working on some legacy code I inherited (why anyone in their right mind would want to build HTML like this is beyond me) but this fixed my problem!